# Local by Flywheel - Adminer - memory exhausted fatal error

Tags: out-of-memory, local, adminer

this is the error when trying to import a 30MB SQL file:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 264241184 bytes) in /Applications/Local.app/Contents/Resources/extraResources/adminer/adminer.php on line 95`

i'm going to try & work my way through this, & will post the answer here if i sort it out. if anyone has a quick/simple fix - please share.
thanks,
Jason

Comment: i've found this post [link](https://localwp.com/community/t/adminer-running-out-of-memory-upon-sql-import-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-174873888-bytes-in-etc-scripts-local-adminer-php-on-line-92/2099) but this doesn't work for me, no such file or directory after following their instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the **Open site shell**

[image: Local Screenshot]

Once you in terminal, move your sql file to your app's public folder, and then run

`wp db import your-file-name.sql`